# WASM and Node.js Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly, emscripten

I have built [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) C++ module as wasm module using the provided make file, that is using the following flags:

```
EMCXX = em++
EMCXXFLAGS = --bind --std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['addOnPostRun', 'FS']" -s "DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0" -s "EXCEPTION_DEBUG=1" -s "FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1" -s "MODULARIZE=1" -s "EXPORT_ES6=1" -s 'EXPORT_NAME="FastTextModule"' -Isrc/
EMOBJS = args.bc autotune.bc matrix.bc dictionary.bc loss.bc productquantizer.bc densematrix.bc quantmatrix.bc vector.bc model.bc utils.bc meter.bc fasttext.bc main.bc
```

The compiled wasm module is available [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js/tree/master/wasm). When I run the module in the provided example [predict.js](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js/blob/master/wasm/predict.js) I get a

```
  var _scriptDir = import.meta.url;
                          ^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
```

caused by

```
var FastTextModule = (function() {
  var _scriptDir = import.meta.url;
  
  return (
function(FastTextModule) {
  FastTextModule = FastTextModule || {};

...
```

**NOTE.**

I had to adapt the compiled module from the original to Node.JS in order to support `require` instead of `import`, but this should not be related to that error.

**UPDATE.**

I have tried the flag `USE_ES6_IMPORT_META` adding to the makefile `-s "USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0"` ad described:

```
em++ --bind --std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['addOnPostRun', 'FS']" -s "DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0" -s "EXCEPTION_DEBUG=1" -s "FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1" -s "MODULARIZE=1" -s "EXPORT_ES6=1" -s 'EXPORT_NAME="FastTextModule"' -s "USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0" -Isrc/  src/args.cc -o args.bc
em++: warning: assuming object file output, based on output filename alone.  Add an explict `-c`, `-r` or `-shared` to avoid this warning [-Wemcc]
```

This time it seems to work, because I get a different error, that is related to the module / code:

```
TypeError: fastTextModule.addOnPostRun is not a function
```

offending line is [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js/blob/master/wasm/fasttext.js#L17):

```
fastTextModule.addOnPostRun(() => {
  if (postRunFunc) {
    postRunFunc();
  }
});
```

while in the modularized file that function is defined [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js/blob/master/wasm/fasttext_wasm.js#L8289)

```
Module["addOnPostRun"] = addOnPostRun;
```

A solution to this problem has been provided [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1173). The final working model is [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js/tree/master/wasm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emscripten provide a `USE_ES6_IMPORT_META` flag! Maybe this can solve your problem.
Take a look at https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js. There is a simple explanation about this flag.

**UPDATE**

Use `USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0`

Comment: okay, so I should modify the make file to support this flag. Thank you I will try this way it makes sense.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to pass the value 0, `USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0` because the default is 1.

Comment: So it seems this does not solve the problem. In fact it should be set as `1` by defaults. Maybe there's something related in the settings.

Comment: ah! (doh) that's way, let me try again then!

Comment: So it seems to work, but I get another error, not sure it's related to the same issue.

Comment: In the Emscripten settings.js file at line 1032, says that "It might not be supported on old browsers / toolchains", Did you try to update your browser, emscripten and node to the latest version?

Comment: This is not valid anymore, since with latest emscripten and when in NodeJS I get a `em++: error: EXPORT_ES6 and ENVIRONMENT=*node* requires USE_ES6_IMPORT_META to be set`