Not allowed to load local resource error when using wasm-gzip in Angular app
I have an Angular 16 app using webpack 5+.  I need to compress/decompress gzip files and thought I would try a WebAssembly library for performance reasons.  However, i'm running into some errors.
I installed wasm-gzip using npm
I created a few static functions to compress/decompress gzip data.
import init, { compress, decompress } from 'wasm-gzip';

import { ArrowColumnMap } from '../store/encounters/arrow-column-map';
import { blobToByteArray, convertArrayToJsonBlob, convertArrayToJsonString } from './array-utils';

export class GzipDataTools {

  public static async compressArrayToGzipBlob(data: any[]): Promise<Blob> {
    const jsonString = convertArrayToJsonString(data, 100_000);
    await init();
    const compressedJson = compress(jsonString);
    const compressedResponse = await new Response(compressedJson);
    return compressedResponse.blob();
  }

  public static async decompressGzipBlobToJson2(blob: Blob): Promise<any> {
    const byteArray = await blobToByteArray(blob);
    await init();
    const decompressedStream = decompress(byteArray);
    const result = await new Response(decompressedStream).json(); // .then((data) => data);
    return result;
  }
}

When i run the app, I get this error:

It seems as if the code is not getting packaged by webpack since it's trying to load the local file. I tried adding the wasm-gzip package code to the assets folder, but that didn't work either.
Any ideas?

Problem comes from import.meta.url. When you have this problem, the wasm library should have been compiled with USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65666725/wasm-and-node-js-cannot-use-import-meta-outside-a-module). But in your case, it's an external dependency. Maybe you should open an issue to the packet maintainer ?
